# Is there any well-populated list or database of pulsar "glitches"?

Tags: pulsar

Besides listing which pulsars have ever actually glitched, it would hopefully also include some historical data on their periods before and after they glitched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two substantial (~650 entries) glitch databases I'm aware of, [one maintained by Jodrell Bank](https://www.jb.man.ac.uk/%7Epulsar/glitches.html) and [one maintained as part of the ATNF's pulsar catalog](https://www.atnf.csiro.au/people/pulsar/psrcat/glitchTbl.html). Both list similar information for each glitch, including the glitch MJD (with ATNF's values sometimes being more precise) and the fractional changes in spin frequency and frequency derivative. References are listed for each entry if you need more information. The databases unsurprisingly overlap (~473 entries, by a count with a quick script), but neither is totally complete.

Comment: fyi I've just asked [What are the main ways that pulsar "glitches" are noticed and documented? Do they have to be caught in the act of glitching to be catalogued?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/48994/7982)